# Cypress - How to have only some env variables checked into source control?

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, cypress

I have two env files, one is `development.json` and the other `production.json`. They have a bunch of env variables like so:

```
{
    "env": {
        "baseUrl": "test.com",
        "freeUserEmail": "test",
        "freeUserPassword": "test123", 
    }
}
```

The file used is determined in the Cypress config file:

```
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const version = config.env.version || 'development'
      const configFile = await import(path.join(
        config.projectRoot,
        'cypress/config',
        `${version}.json`
      ));
```

Scripts look like this:

```
"cypress:open:dev": "cypress open --env version=development",
"cypress:open:production": "cypress open --env version=production"
```

However, I want to move account credentials out of these of files into env files that aren't checked into source control but I want to keep the current files for things like baseUrl which I don't need hidden. Is it possible to have multiple env files for one environment? How would one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the sensitive data into another file, as proposed. I'd use a single file keyed by `version` which means only one file to `.gitignore`.

Use spread operator to merge, but passwords are on `env` key and **spread is shallow**, so you will have to merge at two levels.

**folders**

```js
cypress
  config
    development.json
    production.json
    passwords.json         // exclude from git
```

**passwords**

```js
{
  "development": {
    "freeUserEmail": "test",
    "freeUserPassword": "test123"
  },
  "production": {
    "freeUserEmail": "test2",
    "freeUserPassword": "test456"
  }
}
```

**config setup**

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

      const version = config.env.version || 'development'

      const configFile = await import(path.join(
        __dirname,
        'cypress/config',
        `${version}.json`
      ));

      const passwordsFile = await import(path.join(
        __dirname,
        'cypress/config',
        `passwords.json`
      ));

      // merge config
      config = {
        ...config,                    // take config defined in this file
        ...configFile                 // merge/override from the external file
      }
      config.env = {
        ...config.env,                // 2nd level merge
        ...passwordsFile[version]     // from git-ignored file 
      }

      return config;
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This is great, the type of setup I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try creating file in fixtures folder e.g. `credentials.json` and store your credentials there, this way you can even add them to .gitignore file for safety.
then just use

```
cy.fixtures('credentials').then((credentials) => {
     get('someSelector').type(credentails['freeUserEmail'])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The below example merges content of all config files from current environment to one `configFile` object

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const version = config.env.version || 'development'

      const filesPerEnv = {
        'development': ['file1', 'file2'],
        'production': ['someOtherFile', 'someOtherFile2']
      }

      const configFile = {};

      // Loop trough all files per environment
      // Merge each files content to one `configFile`
      filesPerEnv[version].forEach((fileName) => {
        configFile = {
          ...configFile,
          ...(await import(path.join(config.projectRoot, 'cypress/config', `${fileName}.json`)))
        }
      });
```